# Get "Use Billing Address" from shipping address section of Onepage checkout

Tags: magento

I'm trying to get the gift option message to only show up when a customer is shipping to an address that's different from the billing address in the Onepage checkout flow. I can get the "Ship to same/different address" from the billing section with

```
$this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getData('same_as_billing')
```

and it works great. However, if a customer makes it the shipping methods, and hits back to change the shipping address, that field doesn't seem to get updated. I tried checking

```
$this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getData('use_billing_address')
```

But that data doesn't exist. In fact, when I have these two lines in additional.phtml:

```
Mage::log("Same as billing: ".$this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getData('same_as_billing'));
Mage::log("Use billing: ".$this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getData('use_billing_address'));
```

It doesn't trigger when I go from Shipping Address to Shipping methods. Can anyone give me some direction here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a javascript function instead of PHP, since it doesn't reload the page to get to each section.

In template/giftmessage/inline.phtml, I added the following:

```
    function _showHideGift() {
        var flag=document.getElementById('shipping:same_as_billing').checked;
        if(!flag){
            document.getElementById('gift-messages').style.display="block";
        }else{
            document.getElementById('gift-messages').style.display="none";
    }}
```

And then called the function below the block inside of the CDATA, with the toogleVisilibityOnObjects calls.